# Cross Compiler for Cygwin Target

Tags: linux, windows, gcc, cygwin, cross-compiling

I have been wondering about building Windows executables targeting Cygwin on
a Linux host.
I have not been able to find anything related to a prebuilt crosscompiler and I am lost about how to build one myself with a Cygwin target.

How would I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you target Cygwin from Linux? Cygwin is an emulation layer. Doesn't it make more sense to target native Windows using MinGW-w64?

Answer (score 3):

A cross-tool is available at:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/fedora-cygwin/

A repository for Fedora is at:
https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/yselkowitz/cygwin/

as mentioned on the Cygwin mailing list not so long ago
https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2020-July/245695.html

Answer (score -1):

Is there an actual reason you want to target Cygwin instead of native Windows?

Cygwin introduces a POSIX compatibility layer, while MinGW-w64 targets native Windows.

MinGW-w64 can be installed under most Linux distributions using their respective package managers.

Comment: This might be appropriate as a comment, but it doesn't answer the OP's question at all.